# Python writing to file errors expected string/buffer

Tags: python, regex

I have a code which will replace specific text from keywords iteratively,
Problem:When i provide a file as input i get error

Coding:(works good when text is provided within code)

```
import re, itertools
car = ['skoda', 'audi', 'benz']
text = """
I have a car="mycar"
My friend has a vehicle="myvehicle"
       My uncle have a car="mycar"
Second verse same as the first
"""
it = itertools.cycle(car)
newtext = re.sub(r'mycar|myvehicle', lambda _: next(it), text)
print newtext
```

Coding: when file as input

```
import re, itertools
car = ['skoda', 'audi', 'benz']

with open('ckili.txt','r') as text:
    text1=text.readlines()
    it = itertools.cycle(keywords2)
    newtext = re.sub(r'mycar|myvehicle', lambda _: next(it), text1)

with open('ckili.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(newtext)
```

I get error as:

```
File "C:\Python27\replmay.py", line 8, in <module>
    newtext = re.sub(r'mycar|myvehicle', lambda _: next(it), text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
>>>
```

Please help me to write output into a file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your traceback doesn't match your code. In your traceback, `text` is used, which is a *file object*.

Not that your code works with `text1` either; that is a *list*, not a `str`. Instead of using `readlines()`, use `read()`:

```
with open('ckili.txt','r') as fileob:
    text = fileob.read()
    it = itertools.cycle(keywords2)
    newtext = re.sub(r'mycar|myvehicle', lambda _: next(it), text)
```

or process each line separately. Note that I took the liberty to change the names a little; `text` isn't the best name for a file object.

You appear to be importing the module into your interactive interpreter. Know that module imports are cached, you'll need to explicitly restart your interpreter or reload the module after changes.